# I have a problem of changing spring boot kafka spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers properties

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have been trying to make Spring cloud config server with Kafka for spring cloud config bus.

and but I ran kafka on 172.30.1.111 which has port 9092.

So I set this settting **spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=172.30.1.111:9092**

But I don't understand why it only connects on localhost:9092 in Spring.

The errors are like at startup of Spring boot.

```
[WARN] 2024-02-27 16:00:37,979 [] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient processDisconnection - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-9] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
[WARN] 2024-02-27 16:00:39,198 [] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient processDisconnection - [AdminClient clientId=adminclient-9] Connection to node 1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I have been trying to change this. because I don't want to use localhost. I hope to use other IP.

Below is my pom.xml and spring boot uses JAVA 8(I can't upgrade upper versions.).

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-config-server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.tmatesoft.svnkit/svnkit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.11</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
         </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

and also I tried to add another options but failed.

```
spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=172.30.1.111:9092
spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap-servers=172.30.1.111:9092
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=172.30.1.111:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=172.30.1.111:9092
spring.kafka.streams.bootstrap-servers=172.30.1.111:9092
```

And also it doesn't work by Java Config.
[image]

Why does my setting not work? and How to resolve it to use other IP of Kafka for this?

Comment: why do you have 3 different dependencies for Kafka in pom.xml?

Comment: for Spring cloud bus with Kafka. At First time it was only "spring-cloud-starter-bus-kafka". but it was the same that connection is not changed after spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers=172.30.1.111:9092 at first time. and I tried to find and use other dependencies...

Comment: you just need one dependency. And recheck config files of where it is reading the bootstrap urls

Comment: 1) The error is referring to `spring.kafka.admin.bootstrap-servers`, by the way 2) Kafka returns a list of its advertised.listeners to clients. Maybe your broker is configured to return localhost, and no Spring property will fix that

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you. The root problem is Kafka setting. I took out annotation from config/server.properties of Kafka, revise config file and restart kafka then it works. and also I remove unnecessary dependencies and left only spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers it works too.